# Splitting an address string into a numeric and text parts without using regular expressions

Tags: c#

I'm working in C# and I have lots of strings containing addresses, such as:

> ```
> 10 Downing Street
> Birch Lane 7 
> Palm Creek 8 Street
> 84 Chancellor Place
> Battle on the Somme 56
> ```

and so on.

I need to split these strings into a numeric part(such as "10" or "7")and a textual part (such as "Downing street" or "Birch Lane").

Oh, and I was asked not to use RegEx.

I've tried already to split them in the spaces like this:

```
string s ="84 Chancellor place";
string [] words = s.Split(' ');
```

Problem is that (of course) it doesn't split all string the same way, so I can't always exclude the number from the rest of the text (I don't always know that the number is in words[0] for example, and the textual parts is in different cells and not fused together).

I would much appreciate your help to find a way to extract the digits.

**Edit**:
Desired outputs in each example:

```
string1=10  string2=Downing Street
string1=7   string2=Birch Lane 
string1=8   string2=Palm Creek Street
string1=84  string2=Chancellor Place
string1=56  string2=Battle on the Somme
```

Comment: Please include the wanted output for each of the examples you have posted.

Comment: "I was asked not to use REGEX" seems like a stupid requirement to me as it's the best fit for the job. A bit like asking somebody to move a heavy load without using their arms.

Comment: @spender - Meaning, this is probably homework.

Comment: Oded, its not homework, but a development requirement

Comment: Be TERRIBLY careful that you dont run into bad things. In german some street names include numbers (dates - "street of x may") and one city has sectors (M 4 - the 4 is not a house number, that would be M 4 22). Done that 20 years ago and it turns into a nightmare.

Comment: -1 Why would you be asked not to use regular expressions? Without this information, answers could end up implementing something with the same characteristics as RegEx, which might be the reason you are not allowed to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this loop to initialize a `List<Address>` with the help of `string.Split` and `int.TryParse`:

```
List<Address> addresses = new List<Address>();
foreach (string str in strings)
{
    Address addr = new Address();
    addresses.Add(addr);
    int num, numIndex = int.MinValue;
    string[] tokens = str.Split(new[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(tokens[i], out num))
        {
            addr.Number = num;
            numIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (addr.Number.HasValue)
    {
        // join the rest with white-spaces to the street name skipping the number
        addr.Street = string.Join(" ", tokens.Where((s, i) => i != numIndex));
    }
    else
    {
        addr.Street = str;
    }
}
```

Used this small class:

```
class Address
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/I1RFqq)

**Disclaimer**: note that this is not fail-safe at all if the input is arbitrary. There are many streets that contain numbers as well in the world and there are also numbers with `chars` like "17a".